# C++: Error:class undelared (first use in this function). But I got it declared in hpp file

Tags: c++

I created a class declaration file as fixed.hpp and class definition in fixed.cpp. When I create a object in the main function. The compiler told me that the class is not declared. But I think I did. Any idea or help? Thanks.

---

This is the main.cpp:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <istream>
    #include <ostream>
    #include <sstream>
    #include <stdexcept>

    #include "test.hpp"
    #include "fixed.hpp"

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    { using namespace std;
      fixed f1;
      cout<<f1.value()<<endl;
    }
```

---

This is the fixed.hpp:

```
    #ifndef FIXED_HPP_
    #define FIXED_HPP_

    typedef float value_type ; 

    class fixed
    {
     public:
       fixed();
       fixed(value_type integer, value_type fraction); 
       fixed(double val);

       void as_string();
       value_type integer();
       value_type fraction();
       value_type value();
       static const int places=4;    
       static const int places10=10000;  //scale factor

     private:
       value_type integer_;
       value_type fraction_;   
       //value_type result_;

    };
```

---

This is the fixed.cpp:

```
    #include "fixed.hpp"

    #include <iostream>
    #include <ostream>
    #include <stdexcept>
    #include <string>


    using namespace std;

    //static const value_type fixed::places(4);
    //static const value_type fixed::places10(10000);
    fixed::fixed():integer_(0), fraction_(0){}

    fixed::fixed(value_type                     integer,value_type                         fraction):integer_(integer), fraction_(fraction) 
           {try
       {
        if (fraction_ <0)                          
           throw invalid_argument("Invalid argument. Must be positive.");
       }
    catch (exception& e)
      {
        cout <<"\n"<< e.what() << endl;
      }
     while (fraction_>= places10)
        {
         if(int(fraction_)%10 >=5 && fraction_< (places10*10) )
            fraction_=fraction_/10+1;               
         else
            fraction_/=10;
        }

     //result_ = integer_ + fraction_/places10;  //??
   } 

    fixed::fixed(double val):integer_(int (val)), fraction_(         (val- int(val))*places10) 
           { if (val <0)
        {    val = val*(-1);
             if ( int(val*places10*10)%10>=5)
              fraction_ = (fraction_*(-1) +1)*(-1);
        }     
     else
         {
          if (int(val*places10*10)%10>=5)
              fraction_ = fraction_ +1;
         }

     //result_ = integer_ + fraction_/places10;  //??
   }

    void fixed::as_string()
           {    string str;
                string str2;
                while( (int(integer_)/10) >=0 and int(integer_)>0 )
             {
             str.push_back(int(integer_)%10 + 48);
             integer_ = integer_/10;
             //cout<<str<<endl;
             }
        //cout<<"String format: "<<str<<endl;
        reverse(str.begin(), str.end());
        //cout<<"Reversed format: "<<str<<endl;
        str.push_back('.');
        //cout<<"New string: "<<str<<endl;
        while( (int(fraction_)/10 )>=0 and int(fraction_)>0)
             {
             str2.push_back(int(fraction_)%10 + 48);
             fraction_ = fraction_/10;
             //cout<<str<<endl;
             }
        //cout<<"String format: "<<str<<endl;
        reverse(str2.begin(), str2.end());
        str.append(str2);
        cout<<"String representation: "<<str<<endl;
           }


    value_type fixed::value()
         {
          return   integer_ + fraction_/places10;     
         }
    value_type fixed::integer()
         {
          return integer_;
         }
    value_type fixed::fraction()
         {
          return fraction_;
         }
```

Comment: How are you compiling? What's the exact error message?

Comment: `fixed` is a function in the `std` namespace, which you are `using` - could that be a problem?

Comment: This might just be me, but in my experience header files end with `.h` - not `.hpp`.

Comment: @Mong134 hpp is also valid, the extension is just a convention anyway, any file can be included

Comment: @satuon Hmm, learn something new every day.

Comment: `#endif` missing in fixed.hpp, or just a copy/paste problem?

Comment: @Balint Your comment helped me to figure out a reason for a bug, which occurs due to unintentional char just before  an #endif.

Answer (score 4):

I tried compiling the code, and this was the only significant error:

```
fixed.cpp: In member function ‘void fixed::as_string()’:
fixed.cpp:63:35: error: ‘reverse’ was not declared in this scope
```

I fixed that by using

```
#include <algorithm>
```

in fixed.cpp

Comment: Hi Vaughn, I tried your solution (#include <algorithm>
). But I still got the same old error: 'fixed ' undeclared(first use this function).

Comment: tmpearce is correct. I changed the main.cpp to the following and the issue is resolved. This means 'fixed' is indeed a std function in the namespace. Thank you all guys.                             int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{ //using namespace std;
  fixed f1;
  std::cout<<f1.value();}

Comment: @user1475081 What file/line triggers the error? Please post the _exact_ error.