# C++ expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '&' token

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I got this error expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before'&'token  when I did the operator oveloading. The errors occured in the last 8 lines of fixed.cpp I am not sure what I missed. Any help is appreciated.

This is fixed.hpp

```
    #ifndef FIXED_HPP_
    #define FIXED_HPP_

    typedef float value_type ;  

    class fixed
    {
     public:
       fixed();
       fixed(value_type integer, value_type fraction); 
       fixed(double val);
       void as_string();
       value_type integer();
       value_type fraction();
       value_type value();
       //~fixed();
       fixed& operator+=(fixed other);

       static const int places=4;   
       static const int places10=10000;  

     private:
       value_type integer_;
       value_type fraction_;   
       value_type value_;
    };

    fixed operator+(fixed a, fixed b);

    #endif
```

This is fixed.cpp:

```
    #include "fixed.hpp"

    #include <iostream>
    #include <ostream>
    #include <stdexcept>
    #include <string>
    #include <algorithm>


    using namespace std;

    fixed::fixed():integer_(0), fraction_(0), value_(0){}

    fixed::fixed(value_type integer,  value_type                 fraction):integer_(integer),         fraction_(fraction) 
           {try
       {
        if (fraction_ <0)                          
           throw invalid_argument("Invalid argument. Must be positive.");
       }
            catch (exception& e)
              {
                cout <<"\n"<< e.what() << std::endl;
      }
             while (fraction_>= places10)
                {
                 if(int(fraction_)%10 >=5 && fraction_< (places10*10) )
            fraction_=int(fraction_/10+1);               
         else
            fraction_ =int(fraction_/10);
        }

     value_ = integer_*places10 + fraction_;  
           } 

    fixed::fixed(double val):integer_(int (val)), fraction_( (val- int(val))*places10) 
           { if (val <0)
                {    val = val*(-1);
             if ( int(val*places10*10)%10>=5)
              fraction_ = (fraction_*(-1) +1)*(-1);
        }     
     else
         {
          if (int(val*places10*10)%10>=5)
              fraction_ = fraction_ +1;
         }

     value_ = integer_*places10 + fraction_;  
           }

    void fixed::as_string()
           {    string str;
                string str2;
        while( (int(integer_)/10) >=0 and int(integer_)>0 )
             {
             str.push_back(int(integer_)%10 + 48);
             integer_ = integer_/10;
             //cout<<str<<endl;
             }
        //cout<<"String format: "<<str<<endl;
        reverse(str.begin(), str.end());
        //cout<<"Reversed format: "<<str<<endl;
        str.push_back('.');
        //cout<<"New string: "<<str<<endl;
        while( (int(fraction_)/10 )>=0 and int(fraction_)>0)
             {
             str2.push_back(int(fraction_)%10 + 48);
             fraction_ = fraction_/10;
             //cout<<str<<endl;
             }
        //cout<<"String format: "<<str<<endl;
        reverse(str2.begin(), str2.end());
        str.append(str2);
        cout<<"String representation: "<<str<<endl;
           }   

    value_type fixed::value()
         {
          return   value_;     
         }
    value_type fixed::integer()
         {
          return integer_;
         }
    value_type fixed::fraction()
                {
          return fraction_;
         }
    fixed& fixed::operator+=(fixed other) // error
           { value_ += other.value();
             return *this;     
           }

    fixed operator+(fixed a, fixed b)  //error
          { a+=b;
          return a;}
```

Comment: Unfortunately a lot of books, tutorials, etc. used `using namespace std;` to shorten code, but it leads to problems (like in your example) and should not be used.

Comment: This problem [was identified already](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11158258/1214731).  Is there a reason you're still `using namespace std`?

Answer (score 4):

Your code has lots of problems. Main problem is below:

[`fixed`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/fixed/) is a member of `namespace` std; you are declaring the same name `class` and having an evil `using namespace std;` in your code.

Few other points:

1. Always, make a practice of **not** `using namespace std` at global
   scope. Put `std::` prefix if needed or put `using` inside the
   function scope.
2. `fixed::operator+=(Fixed)`, should be `fixed::operator+=(const
   Fixed&)`; otherwise it will make unnecessary copy.
3. Above comment is true for `operator+(fixed a, fixed b)` also and
   moreover, it does `a += b`, which is wrong. It should be plain `a +
   b` equivalent

Answer (score 2):

Clang provides the following error, which should make it more obvious what is going on:

```
fixed.cpp:90:1: error: reference to 'fixed' is ambiguous
fixed& fixed::operator+=(fixed other) // error
^
./fixed.hpp:6:11: note: candidate found by name lookup is 'fixed'
    class fixed
          ^
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/ios_base.h:950:3: note: candidate found by name lookup is 'std::fixed'
  fixed(ios_base& __base)
  ^
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a classic example of why you shouldn't use `using namespace std;`, you're causing something called namespace pollution by having the same identifiers in the same namespace (since everything from std was pulled in).

First of all, pull in parts of the `std` namespace only when and if you need them by `using std::something;`. Or better yet, learn to appreciate the `std::`, it will make your life a lot easier when you get better at C++ which lives and breathes its standard library.

Second of all, a lot of your code is catastrophic when style is considered, not to mention the bad practices. You're introducing things like:

```
fixed& operator+=(fixed other);
```

There is a lot of problems with this, but the most prominent one is the lack of constness and the fact you're actually passing the instance of the class by value, invoking the copy constructor and making an unnecessary duplicate. The reason you need to use `const` is more of a programmer's safety issue and good practice. You see, you only need to read the incoming value to formulate an answer, a return of the operator. Therefore, making it immutable enables you to safely calculate the result and return it.

```
fixed& operator+=(const fixed& other); // preferably call *other* rhs (righthandside)
```

When you remove the `using namespace std;` or change the name of your class altogether, your initial problems will go away. But there's a lot of things wrong with your operator overloads. Specifically, how you take in parameters, how you return them and managing the situation to do only the things that actually need doing (evading unnecessary copies and temporaries).